# Python json.dump file contains %

Tags: python, json, file, dump

I have a simple python script that writes a dictionary to a file:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import json
import time


token_file_name = "dict.json"

my_dict = {"access_token": "MbwrA4HY1rjUJLrho",
           "expires_in": 1800,
           "refresh_token_expires_in": 7776000
          }   

with open( token_file_name, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
  json.dump(my_dict, f, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)
f.close()
```

I am seeing an weird character(%) at the end of JSON object:

```
╰─➤  cat dict.json 
{
    "access_token": "MbwrA4HY1rjUJLrho",
    "expires_in": 1800,
    "refresh_token_expires_in": 7776000
}%
```

Two questions:

1. How do I eliminate this?
2. Could this case issues when reading a file containing multiple JSON object and if '%' shows between two JSON objects?

Comment: i've tested your code. and not see `%` in the file.

Comment: Can it be related to the other unusual characters that are shown before `cat dict.json`?

Comment: Is the `%` also there if you open the file in a text editor?

Comment: Any chance that's just your shell prompt (and the file you're `cat`-ing doesn't end with a newline)?

Answer (score 3):

The percent sign isn't in your file. Zsh does that when there's no newline at the end of output.

Try this:

```
$ echo -n test
test%
```

The `-n` option omits the newline that `echo` normally inserts.

Comment: Thank you - you were absolutely correct.  It was zsh was adding % to end when displaying the content of the file.